# Firebase performance plugin with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, firebase-performance

Unable to track the slow rendering and frozen frames for compose screens.

I am trying to track slow rendering and frozen frames for the fully compose screens, but firebase is unable to track those screens. however it is able to track the activity.